# What part(s) can I use to connect technic liftarms with modules?

Tags: technic, connections

I have the following setup:

[image: liftarm and module]

How can I connect the liftarm to the stacked bricks? The holes have different distances, so I can't just use black pins. Any suggestions?

Comment: IIRC, the will holes line up every 3 or 4 bricks?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Put two plates between each layer of Technic bricks and the holes will align.

This technique was used commonly in studded Technic sets. Here's [a page from the instructions for 8042](http://peeron.com/scans/8042-1/28/) where you can see this used in several different places:

[image: 8042 page 58,59]

Comment: Are there any pictures of this technique?

Comment: Is this suitable for a strong connection?

Comment: @chicks Added an image for you

Comment: This is one of the times I want to be able to upvote an edit.  Thanks for the helpful picture.

Comment: @nikeee this ist one of the strongest connections used by TLC